# Android webView is not loading URL

Tags: android, webview

SiteLoader.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class SiteLoader extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final WebView SiteLoader = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    SiteLoader.loadUrl("http://m.mysite.com");
    SiteLoader.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  }
}
```

I just generated and installed the signed APK on my android mobile i.e. Karbonn A2+. But it did not load a webpage.

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> was also written in AndroidManifest.xml between <manifest  ..> and </manifest>.

Comment: any errors in log? is internet connected?

Comment: it's perfectly loading in my `WebView`. may be you should move `SiteLoader.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` before `loadUrl()`

Comment: Definitely internet is connected and I just getting a blank screen

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a WebView you'll have to intercept the clicks yourself if you don't want the default Android behaviour.

You can monitor events in a WebView using a WebViewClient. The method you want is shouldOverrideUrlLoading(). This allows you to perform your own action when a particular URL is selected.

You set the WebViewClient of your WebView using the setWebViewClient() method.

If you look at the WebView sample in the SDK there's an example which does just what you want. It's as simple as:

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the site is available, this should work

```
WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```